# Java: set String.format not to display 0 decimal places

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

Is there a way to set String.format so that it won't display 00 decimals?
For example I would like:

```
String.format("%.2f", 12.345d)
```

to display `12.34`
but

```
String.format("%.2f", 12.3d)
```

to display `12.3` instead of `12.30`

Answer (score 7):

Use `DecimalFormat` with setting **rounding** down, like:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN) //rounding off
df.format(12.345d) //12.34
df.format(12.3d) //12.3
df.format(12.00) //12
```

Comment: I prefer RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY myself.  Otherwise your comment of "rounding off" is misleading.  Also RoundingMode.HALF_UP works equally well.

Answer (score 0):

Once you do the inital formatting with `%.2f`, one option is to run the resulting string through a `regex` based `replace`.

The `regex` : `0*$`, should capture all trailing `0s` at the end of the string/number.

So the full method call could be:

```
String.format("%.2f", 12.3).replaceAll("0*$", ""); //Will output "12.3"
```

Comment: While this solves case described in question, it could be worth providing solution for general case like `String.format("%.2f %.2f", 12.3, 1.4)`.

Comment: He would probably also want to get the period (.) in the case where it's double .00.   So perhaps .replaceAll("\\.{0,1}0*$", "") or something.

Comment: @Pshemo that's true, I didn't think of that